# Find value in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

myArray is storing data I need to check before I call a Sub procedure. It has 3 columns:

- Col1: string
- Col2: timestamp
- Col3: string

I need to check:

1. If a string, given by the funcion argument, exists in column 1
2. If it does, then what is the time-difference from now to the newest timestamp of the corresponding string in column 2

   ```
   For n = 1 To UBound(myArray, 2)
       If myArray(1, n) = myString Then
           myTimeStamp = myArray(2, n) 'find the timestamp of this string in col2
           myTimeDiff = DateDiff("n", myTimeStamp, DateTime.Now()) ' calculate the time difference in minutes
           myIndex = n 'return the array index (n)
       End If
   Next n
   ```

   Because the array is filling the timestamps sequentially, I know the latest for a given string in col1 is also the newest.

But myIndex is returning an empty string, why?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in debug mode? That will give you the answer. Also, why is `myIndex` a String??

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett no errors in debug mode. myIndex should be an integer, it is just returning an empty string

Comment: Does your code enter the IF Condition?

Comment: @SiddharthRout YEs, it does.

Comment: Ok Highlight the line `myIndex = n` and step though it and then check the value of `n/myIndex`

Comment: @SiddharthRout I just tested with MsgBox myIndex. It returns an empty box

Comment: what does `MsgBox n` return? Also Check What is the value that you are getting for `UBound(myArray)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout it is returning 3 for both. Is it possible that this array is emptied when formulas are recalculated?

Comment: If `n` is giving you `3` then `myIndex` cannot be `0` Are you using `MSGBOX myIndex` right after the `End If` or somewhere else in the code?

Comment: I'm using it in the immediate window. I get n=3 and myArray also=3. The problem seems to be the array is being emptied from time to time, I guess when formulas recalculate or something, but I still need to figure that out.

Comment: Ok, then while in debug mode, step through your code line by line, and see when exactly this happens.

Comment: *"myArray(2, n) 'find the timestamp of this string in col2"* - Possibly just a confusion of column indices vs. row indices plus counting `UBound` dimension :-)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in VBA usually start with LBound = 0, so your for-loop should be:

```
For n = 0 to UBound(myArray)
```

Comment: I have set "Option Base 1"

Comment: Well, then this isn't the problem... have you declared myIndex? if not, it only exists inside the loop and has the value null outside the loop... you could exit the loop as soon as you find the string. then n is the index you need ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
For n = 1 To UBound(myArray, 1)
    If myArray(n, 1) = myString Then
        myTimeStamp = myArray(n, 2) 'find the timestamp of this string in col2
        myTimeDiff = DateDiff("n", myTimeStamp, DateTime.Now()) ' calculate the time difference in minutes
        myIndex = n 'return the array index (n)
    End If
Next n
```